# How to read and update an object in python plasma?

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I just discovered plasma https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html#putting-and-getting-python-objects
and would like to store an object, get it, update and write back to the store.
Is it possible?
My failing trial looks right now as follows:

```
import pyarrow.plasma as plasma


client = plasma.connect("/tmp/plasma")

obj={'val1':1, 'val2':2,'a':[1,2,3]}
obj_id = client.put(obj)

pobj=client.get(obj_id)

pobj['yyy']=999

#now how to write it back??
client.put(pobj, obj_id) #throws an error: pyarrow.lib.PlasmaObjectExists: object already exists in the plasma store


print("object id: "+str(obj_id))
pobj2=client.get(obj_id)
print("object id2: "+str(pobj2))
```